# Suggetion for a mongoDB query

Tags: database, mongodb

I want to sum the keys of the "packets" object and the "sms_count" values. This is the sample data. Note: The keys of the "packets" object are strings, and I want to convert them into integers before summing.

```
[{
    "_id": "6523af5c4b02ad35149ef816",
    "channel": "Default",
    "date": "2023-10-09T07:00:00.000Z",
    "operator": "test_mobilink78",
    "shortcode": "abc",
    "sms_type": "MT",
    "username": "store365",
    "packets": {
        "1": 5
    },
    "sms_count": 5
},
{
    "_id": "650c2b728aad44dd1bc0b6a7",
    "channel": "Default",
    "date": "2023-09-21T11:00:00.000Z",
    "operator": "test_zong78",
    "shortcode": "abc",
    "sms_type": "MT",
    "username": "store365",
    "packets": {
        "14": 2
    },
    "sms_count": 2
}]
```

I tried running this query and obtained the correct sum for "packets," but I'm not getting the accurate sum for "sms_count."

```
        const pipeline: any = [
        {
            $match: {
                date: {
                    $gte: startOfDay,
                    $lte: endOfDay,
                },
            },
        },
        {
            $addFields: {
                packetKeys: { $map: { input: { $objectToArray: "$packets" }, as: "el", in: { $toInt: "$$el.k" } } }
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$packetKeys"
        },
        {
            $group: {

                _id: {
                    $dateToString: {
                        format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                        date: "$date"
                    }
                },
                smsHits: { $sum: '$sms_count' },
                apiHits: { $sum: "$packetKeys" }
            }
        },

        {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                date: '$_id',
                smsHits: 1,
                apiHits: 1
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: {
                date: 1
            }
        }
    ];
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are there other entries for `packets` besides `"1"`? You'll need to be more complete in your request in order to get good assistance, and I'm pretty sure that the chat bots can probably get you at least pointed in the right direction first

Comment: yes ,there will be any number in the packets object key like this
            {
                "_id": "64fefa7c7507818d73af8d49",
                "channel": "Default",
                "date": "2023-09-11T11:00:00.000Z",
                "operator": "test_mobilink78",
                "shortcode": "99099",
                "sms_type": "MT",
                "username": "Nokia_test_api",
                "packets": {
                    "14": 1
                },
                "sms_count": 1
            }

Comment: Thanks for the additional info and edit. Can you elaborate more on the incorrect sum for `sms_count`? [This playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hjGLIoGS2lC) using your pipeline (minus the `$match`) seems fine at a glance. Do you have other sample data that demonstrates the problem?